# automatically Change txtbox value accourding to combobox

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have some employee Names on column "A" and employee Numbers on column "B" in sheet1. On userform I have a combobox that shows employee names,i want when a name is selected on combobox his/her employee Number shown on a nearby txtbox and i dont know how.

```
Me.cboNames
Me.txtEmployeeNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works

```
Private Sub cboName_Change() '<-- your combobox
    Dim EName As String
    Dim Row As Integer
    EName = Me.cboName.Text
    If EName <> "" Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            Row = .Match(EName, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A100"), 0) '< your combobox data worksheet and range 
            txtEmployeeNumber.Text = .Index(Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2:B100"), Row) '< your textbox data worksheet and range

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (assuming your data is in sheet "Employee"):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

lLastRowEmployee = Worksheets("Employee").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'find las row with data

    For iC = 1 To lLastRowEmployee
        ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets("Employee").Cells(iC, 1) 'load combobox
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    TextBox1 = Worksheets("Employee").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1, 2) 'if combo changes, show employee number in texbox1
End Sub
```

If you like just to show the number, consider using a label instead of a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will load all values to the `ComboBox` (without a loop) from `Worksheets("Sheet4")` (modify to your sheet's name). Afterwards, on the Combo-Box `Change` event it will modify the value in the text box.

**Note**: If you have a header row, and you data starts from the 2nd row, modify the line below :

```
txtEmployeeNumber.Value = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(cboNames.ListIndex + 1, 2)
```

to:

```
txtEmployeeNumber.Value = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(cboNames.ListIndex + 2, 2)
```

**Code** (inside the `User_Form` module):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboNames_Change()

txtEmployeeNumber.Value = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(cboNames.ListIndex + 1, 2)

End Sub
```

'=========================================================================

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim LastRow As Long

cboNames.Clear
With Worksheets("Sheet4") '<--replace "Sheet4" with the sheet you have your employees data
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    cboNames.List = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai,I put the code in UF module(both) but it gives compile error"Variable not defined"`txtEmployeeNumber.ValueWorksheets("Sheet4").Cells(**cboNames**.ListIndex + 1, 2)`

Comment: You know i use excel 2007 and I have no idea about  `ListIndex` and i dont see it in **cbonames** properties window

Comment: @Mansour is your Combo-Box named `cboNames` located in a User_form ?

Comment: you can't this code worked with the 2 user_form controls you mentioned, you should find a way to copy >>paste them inside your code

Comment: Sorry , i shouldn't mention about 2 other controls,i didn't try the code with those yet. my problem still exists.