# VBA - Add item to combobox from dynamically created listview

Tags: vba, excel

I need load ComboBox3 with items from ListView3 that is dynamicaly changed by value in ComboBox1.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Call filterlist

'This line is what I need to change. Not working in this way
UserForm1.ComboBox3.AddItem = ListView3.ListItems 
End Sub
```

Sub to filter values :

```
Private Sub filterlist()
Dim item As ListItem
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sonsat As Long

Set ws = Sheets("data")

ListView3.ListItems.Clear

 sonsat = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 2 To sonsat
    If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = ComboBox1.Text Then
        Set item = ListView3.ListItems.Add(, , ws.Cells(i, 1))
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws.Cells(i, 2)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws.Cells(i, 3)


    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I know, once a combo-box is rendered the only way of adding to the list is to destroy the combo-box and recreate it - with the updated list of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not shure what you mean by "dinamically change". I'm just guessing, but see next example. If your data structure is as the image, and you want to load A, B and C in your ComboBox1 and, after selecting A in combo1 you want combo2 to fill with 101, 1010, 102 and so, try the code below.

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim dU1 As Object, cU1 As Variant, iU1 As Long, lrU As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Set dU1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lrU = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    cU1 = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & lrU) 'Starts in second row. First row left for titles
    For iU1 = 1 To UBound(cU1, 1)
        dU1(cU1(iU1, 1)) = 1
    Next iU1

    'now dU1 has unique values from column A

    For i = 0 To dU1.Count - 1
        ComboBox1.AddItem dU1.Keys()(i) 'Load Combobox1 with unique values from Column A
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    ComboBox2.Clear
    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lLastRow
        If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) = ComboBox1.Text Then
            ComboBox2.AddItem (Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not bad idea, but I was little bit misunderstood. If you are using scripting. dictionary without include listview, then I need load only one column.Check my img with example.
[link](http://imgur.com/a/fiNd5)

Comment: I edited your code for exact fit to my question. This is different way how solve this, but useful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The AddItem() method only allows one object to be added at a time, it looks like you are passing the entirety of the ListView items at once. Instead, you should iterate over the ListView items:

```
For Each item in ListView3.ListSubItems
    ComboBox.AddItem(item.Text)
Next item
```

Comment: Or transpose without a loop (see @Shai Rado answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42326890/1726522)).

Comment: Very clever, hadn't thought of that!

Comment: @aitchpat Hm, this is way how to fill ComboBox, but without delete old items  is not what I need. (ComboBox.clear is not possible use here) Anyway thanks for this. This is answer for my question. I need to change the way how list filter and combo box  works right now.

Comment: Why you can't use ComboBox.Clear? See my answer below.