# Filtering a ListBox to only include unique values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

i have a simple Excel/VBA problem:

What i want to create is a (single-select) ListBox where I want to show unique values of Data i have on a different worksheet.

So far I have a ListBox like this:

[image]

And a named selection of the data i want to show:

[image]

I used a formula like this and used that as the input for the ListBox.

[image]

The formula: =BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(TopicData!$C$1;1;0;ANZAHL2(TopicData!$C:$C)-1;1)

Now my question is: How can i get the ListBox to show only unique values? I am familiar with vba, so a solution including this would be totally fine. In fact I already tried to remove duplicate entries in vba, whenever there is a change to the ListBox, but for some reason nothing seems to work.

Here is my vba script where I tried to solve this:

unfortunatley I always get a "Error 400" when I trie to call *RemoveItem* on the ListBox.

```
' ...
' filter listbox content so only unique values remain
Dim i As Integer

' find duplicates
Dim inList As New Collection
Dim indexesToRemove As New Collection

For i = availableTopicsListBox.ListCount - 1 To 1 Step -1
    If CollectionContains(inList, availableTopicsListBox.List(i)) Then
        ' if it is already in the list, remove it
        indexesToRemove.Add i
    Else
        inList.Add availableTopicsListBox.List(i)
    End If
Next i

' remove duplicates
Dim j As Integer
For j = indexesToRemove.count To 1 Step -1
    availableTopicsListBox.RemoveItem (indexesToRemove(j))
Next j
'...
```

Comment: you should step through the Topic column and have an array that contains the unique values. Then check if the cell in the Topic column is in the array, if not add it, else next row.

Comment: try using a oledb connection to the sam eworkbook... writing a query to get the distinct values and copy them to a range in a sheet and refferencethat range.....be sure to make the range a list object.... so that the values gets updated....no matter the number of unique values

Comment: you should use a `Dictionary` to store all unique keys from your range (I think column C:C), then only add unique keys to your `availableTopicsListBox`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42365856/1726522) is an example for filling a ComboBox with uniques values making use of a Dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will use the `Dictionary` to store only unique values from column C (in "TopicData" worksheet), and then populate `availableTopicsListBox` listbox with only the unique values inside the `Dictionary`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim Dict As Object
Dim Key As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim C As Range

With Sheets("TopicData") '<-- I think this is your sheet's name
    ' find last row with data in column "C"
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each C In .Range("C1:C" & LastRow)
        If C.Value <> "" Then ' <-- skip empty cells
            If Not Dict.exists(C.Value) Then
                Dict.Add C.Value, 1
            End If
        End If
    Next C
End With

' loop through all unique keys, and add them to the listbox
For Each Key In Dict.keys
    availableTopicsListBox.AddItem Key
Next Key

End Sub
```

Comment: @Florian Baierl have you tried my code above ? is it working as you intended ?

Comment: I tried it today and it works. :) Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ShaiRado this is the best solution I have found which solved my similar problem perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: @HW-Scientist you're welcome :) that's an old answer